# Roadworks datasets or API services

Tags: data-request, usa, api, europe

Hi guys I need to integrate into my app data about road conditions for major cities in Europe and U.S. initially. I'm looking for data about roadworks mainly but would be cool to find a feed for road conditions and hazards like uneven surfaces or potholes.
Ideally I'd like use some API-based service but I'd be ok also referring to some dataset periodically updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can apply to use the freely available Waze API for road conditions  here.
https://www.waze.com/sdk

For road conditions in Europe there are links for Austria, Belgium, France, Germany, Italy, Netherlands, UK, and Switzerland here
http://europerides.com/rideblog/road-conditions/

For road conditions in the United States you can look at each states Department of Transportation (DOT).
https://www.fhwa.dot.gov/about/webstate.cfm

Another possibility for information about road conditions is Transitland's feed registry.
https://transit.land/feed-registry/